# GLSL gl_FragDepth equivalent in Metal shaders

Tags: ios, opengl-es, metal

I'm looking to adjust a fragments depth in a Metal shader. Previously I was achieving this via GLSL's built-in output variable [gl_FragDepth](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader/Defined_Outputs). Is there an equivalent approach using Apple's Metal shaders on iOS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you specify this with the `depth` attribute on a member of the struct you return from your fragment shader. For example, you'd create a type such as:

```
struct FragmentOut {
    half4 color [[color(0)]];
    float depth [[depth(any)]];
};
```

Then, in your fragment function, create an instance of this struct, populate, and return it:

```
fragment FragmentOut my_frag_function(...) {
    FragmentOut out;
    out.color = // compute fragment color (for first color attachment)
    out.depth = // compute fragment depth
    return out;
}
```

Note that rather than `any`, you can specify one of `greater` or `less` as the depth attribute argument, which indicates that the fragment depth you provide will be, respectively, greater than or less than the interpolated fragment depth. The semantics of these specifiers match those of the same name in OpenGL, and you should use them when possible for optimization purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer. As a follow-up, does Metal make available the interpolated fragment depth in the fragment shader, or will that need to be calculated manually?

Comment: @ndg, that's available via a `[[position]]`-attributed input parameter. The `.z` component is the interpolated depth.